# Python: Can iterate sub elements using elementTree

Tags: python, xml, iterator, elementtree

I have the following code to parse an XML but it just won't let me iterate through the children:

```
import urllib, urllib2, re, time, os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

def wgetUrl(target):
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(target)
        req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3 Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        outtxt = response.read()
        response.close()
    except:
        return ''
    return outtxt

newUrl = 'http://feeds.rasset.ie/rteavgen/player/playlist?showId=10056467'

data = wgetUrl(newUrl)
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
#tree = ET.parse(data)
for elem in tree.iter('entry'):
    print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

Now, If I remove 'entry' from the iter I get an output like this (Why the URL??):

```
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry {}
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id {}
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}published {}
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}updated {}
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title {'type': 'text'}
```

But, If I put the iter statement like this it still does not find the children to entry:

```
for elem in tree.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
    print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

I still only get the entry element on it's own, not the children:

```
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry {}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I have searched everywhere but can't figure this out... I am new to all this so sorry if it is something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are parsing a Atom feed, you *really* want to use the [`feedparser` library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser/) instead, which takes care of all these details for you and many more.

The `{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}` part is a namespace. You need to specify that namespace to select the `entry` tags:

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('ns:entry', {'ns': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}):
```

where I used a dictionary to map the `ns:` prefix to the namespace, or you can use the same curly braces syntax:

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
```

Once you have the element, you still need to explicitly find it's children:

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
    for child in elem:
        print child
```

Comment: Even if I use for elem in tree.iterfind('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
    print elem.tag, elem.attrib it still doesn't iterate down to the children e.g. (<id>, <published>, <updated>, <title> etc.). Any idea why?

Comment: @user1995132: Yes, you are searching for `entry` only, it won't find the children then. You are asking for `entry` tags, not `id` or `published` or `updated` or `title` tags.

Comment: Even with tree.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry') it didn't work so when I saw your example I tried iterfind but same result..

Comment: @user1995132: Just tested against that feed, I find the one element with `iterfind()` just fine.

Comment: @user1995132: Did I mention that using `feedparser` would be much easier already?

Comment: Yeah, I can find it too. The problem is that <entry> has the children <id>10038711</id><published>2012-07-04T12:00:00+01:00</published><updated>2013-01-06T12:31:25+00:00</updated><title type="text">Reeling in the Years</title>..... And many more and I thought by using that iter command it would step through the children? I want to pull values off them?

Comment: I must have a look at feedparser to see if it can handle it.. I have tried so much alreay (regex, beautifulSoup, minidom, elementTree) and now to look at another...

Comment: @user1995132: The feedparser library has been around for a long time and has been *specifically designed* to parse Atom and RSS feeds.